# Wrong menu coming in theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have registered a menu like so in my theme setup:

```
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'understrap' ),
        'footer_1' => __( 'Footer 1', 'understrap' ),
        'footer_2' => __( 'Footer 2', 'understrap' ),
        'footer_3' => __( 'Footer 3', 'understrap' )
    ) );
```

and in my footer used this html

```
            <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block col-lg-2 text-md-center text-lg-left">
                <?php
                $args1 = array(
                        'menu' => 'footer_1'
                );
                wp_nav_menu($args1);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block col-lg-2 text-md-center text-lg-left" >
                <?php
                $args2 = array(
                    'menu' => 'footer_2'
                );
                wp_nav_menu($args2);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-2 mobile-footer-nav text-md-center text-lg-left">
                <?php
                $args3 = array(
                    'menu' => 'footer_3'
                );
                wp_nav_menu($args3);
                ?>
            </div>
```

In admin I have set different menus to each menu space but footer_1 outputs to all 3 areas.

Why does footer_1 output to all 3?  I cannot see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use theme_location paramter in `wp_nav_menu()` and change it accordingly footer_2 & footer_3

```
<?php
    $args1 = array(
        'menu' => 'footer_1',
        'theme_location' => "footer_1"
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $args1 );
?>
```